# Log errors to file but not display in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

When running a Codeigniter application in production I want to be able to log errors in particular PHP errors.  The issue is that with CI to log PHP errors requires the CI log level to be set to error or higher which in turn displays these errors to screen.  In by production environment I want to log these errors to a log file but not display them on screen.

Has anyone been able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In **Codeigniter Version 3.1.10**
If you want log errors but don't want to display it on the screen on Production environment,

then you have to change value of environment variable in your main root file `index.php` and search for variable `ENVIRONMENT` and change it.

**by default** it will be as follows:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');
```

**change it to as**:

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'production');
```

now error will not be display on screen,

But you want to log that errors so you have to change config file's `log` variable which is in 
`application/config/config.php`

**by default** it will be:

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
```

**change it to as**:

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

now in logs folder log files will be created date wise, where you can see php errors logged.

options explained for `log_threshold` variable:

```
0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
2 = Debug Messages
3 = Informational Messages
4 = All Messages
```

For a live site you'll usually only enable Errors (1) to be logged otherwise
 your log files will fill up very fast.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i think you need to set display errors to 0 and error_reporting to e_all

```
ini_set("display_errors",1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I have already tried that but the CI error handler ignores this and displays the error on screen based on the log_threshold value and nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

Set the following things in config/config.php:

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;

$config['log_path'] = 'appropriate path of the file';
```

And you can place the following line anywhere in the application (like in controller or model or helper).

```
log_message('info', 'some message');
```

After executing the application one log file will be created by a name with current date.

If you check that file you will get the log messages.

If your message is printing means your file executing properly and till that log_message() function it is executing. You can check place the line multiple times and check.

hope my answer is useful. If not please comment. i will try to resolve your problem.

Reference link : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to log messages in CI.  What I can't see how I can log errors in production so these are saved to the log file but not actually displayed on the screen to the end user.